# What are the names given to these 2 LINQ expressions

Tags: linq

I'm trying to find the correct names for these 2 "types" of coding expressions in LINQ so that I can refer to them correctly. I want to say that the first is called "Fluent Style"?

```
var selectVar = arrayVar.Select( (a,i) => new { Line = a });

var selectVar =
    from s in arrayVar 
    select new { Line = s };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- First - calling an extension method. 
  This style of coding is called "[fluent interface](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html)" as you mentioned.
- Second method is called [language integrated query](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query)

Answer (score 1):

The first isn't even really LINQ, it's a lambda expression, with a type invariant object created.

```
(a) => new { blah = b}
```

The second is a LINQ query filling an on the fly class that has a property Line.
 There is no hashrocket operator in this one, so this one is just plain old linq.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the second form is "query comprehesion syntax", which the compiler translates into the first form.